# Player owned structure laboratory permissions

Tags: eve-online

I would like to open up one of my mobile laboratories so that corporate members can start their own research jobs. I have done a bit of googling but haven't found anything recent that discusses this in depth. The exact situation that I want to allow is as follows;

Corporate members...

- can create their own research jobs
- cannot cancel other research jobs
- must store their own blueprints in their own hangar at a nearby station
- cannot take other members blueprints

My initial impression on this is that many years ago (2008) it simply wasn't possible, and that more recently (2011) some improvements had been made that allowed further customisation but still didn't completely fulfill these requirements (ie: members needed the "factory manager" role and access to the corporate wallet, which would allow them to cancel other people's jobs and steal their blueprints). This seems like something that a game with as much depth of EVE wouldn't have overlooked.

Is this still the case? Is there any way to work around these limitations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is still the case and people could still take other people's blueprints and cancel their jobs etc. You also cannot do research from your own hangar, it must be done from the corporate hangar.

There is no workaround for it at the moment.

Source: I am Director of an Industry Corp and the Corporate Starbase Manager.

Answer (score 1):

**Indeed, as user28015 mentioned, it still works this way.**

**Tested ideas for a process / trust - based workaround :**

Working around these limitations must be done through processes, and not game mechanics.

For example, in my corporation there is a "Head of Research" and two "Senior Researchers" who have the required roles. Private contracts are used by other members to give the BPO to the researcher, in exchange for a collateral. (Which is *less* than the value of the BPO.)
When the task is complete, the researcher will return the blueprint to its owner, and will retrieve their collateral along with a bonus to pay the corporation fee.

This runs smoothly if you have trusted "Researchers" in sufficient numbers so they don't paralyze research when absent, plus it also allows them to prioritize jobs depending on who's asking, context, usefulness of BP for corp activities, etc.

From experience, you may want to keep the collateral low. In a corp with proper screening and sound processes to climb the ranks, there is more risk of users scamming researchers of their collateral money (if high) than researchers keeping an expensive BPO for themselves.

Of course, the occasional sleeping agent who turns after 3 years of good services can still happen, but this is EVE. It's not really a matter of if a treason will happen, it's more a question of when...